# Windows jruby interpreter doesn't recognize class changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, jruby

I'm new to ROR and I'm using jruby on Windows. When I make changes to a class in the lib folder or in the models folder, the interpreter doesn't recognize it and I have to stop the rails server and restart it to get it to recognize my changes. Clearly, it's wasting a lot of my time. This problem doesn't happen when I make changes to the controller. The guy sitting next to me uses a Mac and says that this shouldn't be happening and that maybe it's a problem with jruby and Windows.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me? I would to know how to have my code changes recompiled without having to stop and restart rails everytime.

Oh yeah - I just installed ROR a couple weeks ago so all my versions are very current.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this was due to my newbie mistake of not naming the file correctly. The class name should be camel case (e.g. EmailLibrary), but the filename should be standard ruby lower case (e.g. email_library.rb). This is due to the Rails framework seeing the class name of "EmailLibrary" and then looking for the file "email_library.rb" and it not finding it. Thus it doesn't get refreshed by Rails automatically.